# "waterfall" javascript requests to API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So we have an endpoint on our API which creates a new entity.  There is a possible situation where we call this endpoint 200+ at once..  This sometimes crashes our API so we want to try an approach where we send maybe 25 at a time, wait for the responses, then try 25 more until all 200+ are done.  Is there a way to do this in angularJS or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) utility library for this, for example the [`parallelLimit`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallelLimit) function.

Quick example:

```
var limit = 25
async.parallelLimit([
    function(callback) {
        // do your request, and call callback(error, result)
    },
    function(callback) {
        // do your request, and call callback(error, result)
    }
    // ... more async functions
], limit, function(err, results) {
    // err and results contain your errors and results
});
```